# Show work area in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Is there any way to make the edges of the work area in PowerPoint always show?

One of my colleagues often makes presentations for our meetings, and when she adds images they are often in higher resolution than the presentation itself. This means that the whole image wont show, but you can't see the edges of the work area since they are behind the images. 
When she the centers some text in the image it wont be centered in the presentation.

Example image:
[image: Image in PP]
This is a screenshot from PowerPoint. The image is in crop-view, and the currently cropped size is that same as the work area. When I got it it wasn't cropped.

So is there any option or something I can show her so that she instantly sees when the images exceed the work area?

(I'm using PP2013, I believe she is as well.)

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: Sorry, this doesn't directly answer your question about how to show her the image has exceeded the work area, but it is a way to work with images so they don't. I don't know that there is a tool to do what you seek.*

---

If you are using placeholders, use the "insert image" icon to add the images.

[image]

The image will automatically resize to fit the placeholder size.

If you need to [Add a placeholder to a layout](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-placeholder-to-a-layout-a8d93d28-66cb-43fd-9f9d-e12d0a7a1f06), you can do so from the Slide Master.

[image]